# Formik on submit not called with Nextjs13

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js, formik, formik-material-ui

i created a form in nextjs13 using Formik, Material UI and Yup, but upon click the submit buttom the form get append to the url as queries and the onSubmit button is never called.

i already have `use client` at the top of my page, yet the validation and onsubmit is not working

below is my form, i cant realy figure out what am doing wrongly

```
      <Formik
        validationSchema={validationSchame}
        initialValues={{
          username: "",
          password: "",
        }}
        onSubmit={async (values, formikHelpers) => {
          console.log(values);
        }}
      >
        {({ errors }) => {
          return (
            <Form>
              <Grid item sx={{ marginBottom: 1 }}>
                <Field
                  sx={{ width: "300px" }}
                  name="username"
                  as={StyledRedditTextField}
                  placeholder="Username"
                  label="Username"
                  size="medium"
                />
              </Grid>
              <Grid item>
                <Field
                  sx={{ width: "300px", marginBottom: 2 }}
                  name="password"
                  as={StyledRedditTextField}
                  placeholder="Password"
                  label="Password"
                  size="medium"
                  type="password"
                />
              </Grid>

              <Grid item>
                <Button
                  type="submit"
                  variant="contained"
                  color="primary"
                  sx={{ width: "300px" }}
                  size="large"
                >
                  Sign In
                </Button>
              </Grid>
            </Form>
          );
        }}
      </Formik>
```